# How can an equivalence relation in Set be described by a coequalizer in Set?

Tags: category-theory

From Mac Lane's Category Theory:

> If $E'$ is an equivalence relation on a set $X$, show that the usual set of equivalence classes $X/E'$ can be described by a coequalizer in Set.

I know a coequalizer of $f,g: X \rightarrow Y$ in Set is an arrow $u : Y \rightarrow Y/E$ where $E$ is the least equivalence relation which contains all pairs $\langle f(x),g(x) \rangle$ for $x \in X$, $uf=ug$, and for every $h : Y \rightarrow Z$ there's a unique $h' : Y/E \rightarrow Z$ such that $h' \circ u = h$,

but I'm having trouble seeing a relationship between the arrow $u$ and the set $X/E'$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's not completely clear; do you realize that the goal is to have the coequalizer map be the the standard projection map $X \to X / E'$ that sends an element to its equivalence class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation. Let $Z=\{(x,x')\in X\times X:x\sim x'
\}$. Define $f:Z\to X$ by $f(x,x')=x$ and $g:Z\to X$
by $g(x,x')=x'$. What's the coequaliser of $f$ and $g$?